# Can't get Exception Controller working - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

```
namespace etc...

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyExceptionController extends ExceptionController
{
    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $format = 'html')
    {


    }
}
```

Doing nothing inside the controller returns a "Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in..." error. Not sure if that's right, or if that's another problem. I'd expect it to just do the usual action.

I just need to do it so it shows a specified route exactly as it would if I went to domain.com/page.

I've tried this:

```
   $httpKernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
   $response = $httpKernel->forward('AcmeMyBundle:Default:pageAction');
   $this->setResponse(new Response($response));
```

...but get this error:

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object in...
```

Comment: `Call to a member function get() on a non-object in` is a typical case when you are calling a function on a `$something` that should be an object, but is `null` instead. Please give us more and complete message, in order to help.

Comment: Just ignore it then. I just need to know how to access the $controller->forward in an Exception Controller. $this->container->get() obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks similar to something I did yesterday. I wanted to get all NotFoundHttpException Exception and try to forward them to a default controller. I achieved this with an exception listener like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class NotFoundHttpExceptionListener
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            $httpKernel = $this->container->get('http_kernel');

            $response = $httpKernel->forward(
                'AcmeMyBundle:Controller:action',
                array(
                    'uri'  => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                )
            );

            $response->headers->set('X-Status-Code', '200');
            $event->setResponse($response);
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that X-Status-Code is necessary if you want to return another status code than 404 because the handleException method in HttpKernel will use this to set the final status code and removes it from the header section.

My services.yml looks something like this:

```
notfoundhttp.exception.listener:
  class: Acme\MyBundle\Listener\NotFoundHttpExceptionListener
  calls:
    - [ setContainer, [@service_container] ]
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Comment: Method 'forward' on http_kernel is deprecated. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, as method 'forward is actually deprecated you can make the response this way:       $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('main_homepage');
            
            $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($url);